# Get List of all the SonarQube Issues at once

Tags: sonarqube

Is there any possibility to get the list of all the SonarQube issues with single API or any other process ?

I have used below API but it only displays first 500 results, If I run the API again it displays the same values which gave for first run ..

/api/issues/search?componentKeys=&ps=500

I have used createdBefore and After parameters in the above API but not getting the exact values.

At a time I suppose to get only 500 issues but in my project we have around thousands of sonar issues.. we just want to get the entire list of issues in any spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can find text about exporting data in csv file](https://sdipesh.medium.com/export-vulnerabilities-issues-into-csv-from-sonarqube-community-developer-edition-5cf39b9be580) and [here you can find PowerShell script to do that](https://gist.github.com/ddemeyer/80a2016e1ae580d374658692e798aaa7#file-export-sonarqubeproject-ps1)